# Looping through non-closed tags?

Tags: html, vb.net, html-agility-pack

Hi and thanks in advance.

I am trying to use HTMLAgilityPack in VB.NET to loop through a collection of `<td>` tags in a table. They are contained inside `<tr>` tags (naturally).

I have created the loop below to access the TR's and TD's as required:

```
For Each tr In table.SelectNodes(".//tr")
    For Each td In tr.SelectNodes("td")
        '(Handle td's here)
    Next
Next
```

The problem is that the HTML of the website is missing an end tag on one particular TD in their template. This causes one 3 TD's to be picked up in each loop as it sees the 3rd TD as an endless tag encompassing all the others. For example:

```
<tr>
    <td>Div 1 info</td>
    <td>Div 2 info</td>
    <td>Div 3 info
    <td>Div 4 info</td>
    <td>Div 5 info</td>
</tr>
```

My question is how can I fix this to loop through the FULL collection of TD's? I tried to check if TR.Count is 3 then update tr(2).InnerHTML inserting a  tag where appropriate. It just doesn't update.

I would appreciate any help you can provide! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `HtmlDocument.OptionFixNestedTags` property:

```
Dim html = New HtmlDocument
html.OptionFixNestedTags = True
html.LoadHtml(File.ReadAllText(htmlFile))
Dim table As HtmlNode = html.DocumentNode
For Each tr In table.SelectNodes(".//tr")
    For Each td In tr.SelectNodes("td")
        Console.WriteLine(td.InnerText.Trim())
    Next
Next
```